# GO: No change happened when use rpc call to change my bool value

Tags: go, rpc

Apologize for my poor English First.

When I try to learn go net/rpc. Something happen unexpected and I don't know why. I tried to use google to find it out but failed.

my code is:

```
func CallDone(id int8) {

    args := DoneArgs{}

    args.Done = true

    args.Id = id

    reply := DoneReply{}

    reply.GotIt = true

    ok := call("Coordinator.Inform", &args, &reply)

    if ok {

        fmt.Printf(" Task %v complete %v\n", id, reply.GotIt)

    } else {

        fmt.Print("Failed\n")

    }

}
```

I set the reply.GotIt to `false` on the server and print it. but it is still true.

if I delete the `reply.GotIt = true`, everything will happen as expected.
Or I change the type of `reply.GotIt` from `bool` to `int`, the change will happen as expected too. Only the `bool` will not change.

my go version is: `go version go1.21.3 linux/amd64`

---

10.30 refreshed:

Server side:

```
func CallDone(id int8) {
    args := DoneArgs{}
    args.Done = true
    args.Id = id

    reply := DoneReply{}
    reply.GotIt = true

    ok := call("Coordinator.Inform", &args, &reply)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf(" Task %v complete %v\n", id, reply.GotIt)
    } else {
        fmt.Print("Failed\n")
    }
}
```

Client side had just been shown above

the data structure is:

```
type DoneReply struct {
    GotIt bool
}
```

both the server and the client share the data structure, because they are all run in my localhost.

Comment: It's hard to finalise the root cause of this issue. Can we get server and client side complete code? Also, could you check `reply.GotIt` has same data type on both server and client side?

Comment: Thank you for willing to help! I've refreshed my question above.@AshutoshSingh